# Create a new branch with the last master updates (when it was already been created)

Tags: git, branch, rename

I've had a problem when creating a new branch (DAT-820) as I haven't done the git pull (on master branch) before creating it, so I do not have the latest updates...
My ticket has this name "DAT-820" and I want to maintain this name for the branch. How can I manage this? I want to start the new branch DAT-820 but with the master latest updates (and the branch DAT-820 already exists, but does not have the master updates)

Comment: You could delete the branch, then git pull, then checkout master, then create the branch again. Or you could merge master into your branch

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was not possible!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any changes on your branch you can simply run (any uncommitted changes will be LOST:

`git reset master --hard`

Otherwise, depending on practices in the project you can:

`git rebase master`

which will apply all commits from your branch on top of master

`git merge master`

it will add changes from master but in a form of merge - the commit history will not be so clean, but can generate less conflicts.